# angular2 - Pass value from parent route to child route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, components, ngroute

I have a route called home and it has three child routes, documents, mail and trash. In the home route component it has a variable called 'user'. I know there are a few ways of passing info between parent and child components highlighted [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html), but how am I suppose to pass info between parent/child routes.

```
{ path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent, children: [
        { path: 'documents',  component: DocumentsComponent },
        { path: 'mail',  component: MailComponent },
        { path: 'trash',  component: TrashComponent },
    ]
},
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
  // Mock user, for testing  
  myUser = {name:"John", loggedIn:true};
  // Is Super Admin
  isLogged():boolean {
    if(this.myUser.role == true){
      return true ; 
    }
    return false ; 
  }
}
```

Component

```
  constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http, private homeService: HomeService) {

  }

  isLogged(){
    return this.homeService.isLogged(); 
  }
```

Template

```
<div class="side-nav fixed" >
    <li style="list-style: none">
        <img alt="avatar" class="circle valign profile-image" height="64" src=
        "../images/avatar.jpg" width="64">
        <div class="right profile-name">
            <!-- Value not changing even with service --> 
            {{myUser.role}} 
        </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a common service to pass data like explained in the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)

Basically you may create a Service which will have a user object, which can be updated once your parent route gets loaded or with some action on parent component.

**UserService**

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

   @Injectable()
   export class UserService {
     // Observable user 
     user = new Subject<string>();
   }
```

And then when the child route component gets loaded you may retrieve the value from the Service.

**HomeComponent**

```
 @Component({
   ... 
 })
 export class HomeComponent{
   ... 
   constructor(private userService:UserService ){}
   someMethod = () =>{
      this.userService.user.next(<pass user object>);
   }
 }
```

**MailComponent**

```
 @Component({
   ... 
 })
 export class HomeComponent{
   ... 
   constructor(private userService:UserService ){
     this.userService.user.subscribe(userChanged);  
   }

   userChanged = (user) => {
     // Do stuff with user
   }
 }
```

Service object will be same instance in child if you add the provider in the parent.

Comment: Doesn't work for you as in, you are not able to implement this or you have some different scenario? If different scenario please add more details.

Comment: In my html template i have an ngIf to check if the user is logged in. However, its not reading the service method that checks.

Comment: you may add a variable which can be updated based upon the subscription, and use it in the ngIf in child component.

Comment: Yeah that could work. So im giong to have to import this service for every component i have ? Is there another way?

Comment: Okay, so i tried the variable thing you suggested and that works, but when i try change the user info, the parent and child are not talking. One will have the user logged in and the other will have the user logged out.

Comment: are you calling this.userService.user.next(new user info object) again when you change user info in parent?

Comment: Im not using the methods you pulled off the website, im using my own.

Comment: I guess ill just have to make a new question to figure out why the service info doesn’t change. Thanks anyway

Comment: `user: Subject<string> = new ReplaySubject(1)` works for me

Comment: I understand the simple case here, where the service is used essentially like a simple shared global object - but how does this work if I have multiple instances of main component - in tabs or in a list. Does the DI container automatically give the same instance to the child or do I have to manage some kind of additional 'key' if I'm sharing this service?

Comment: To followup, the section "Parent and children communicate via a service" from https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service explains that `The scope of the service instance is the parent component and its children. Components outside this component subtree have no access to the service or their communications.`

Comment: @MadhuRanjan "Service object will be same instance in child if you add the provider in the parent." This sentence saved my life. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out :- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array

You can pass data while changing routes on click as :-

```
<a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center', { foo: myVar }]">Crisis Center</a>
```

Comment: How and where do you access that object passed? `ActivatedRoute.data`?